# Plank issues: not showing active programs nor reopen minimized windows

Tags: 16.04, unity, plank

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity and Plank 0.11.3, with the GTK theme. Plank won't show the active apps -even the pinned ones- and, if I switch to a different window/program, instead of reopening the minimized window of the program on click in its icon, it will open a new instance of it.

Is this a default behavior? Can I fix it somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04. To modify slighty moofus answer, turn off Show Unpinned but don't reboot. Just quit Plank and launch it again. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem (on Manjaro XFCE, however), and the fix for me was simple:  Turn off the Show Unpinned option in Preferences, reboot, and turn it back on.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

This happened again recently on Arch Linux and related distros, where the root cause appears to be a newer version of `libwnck3` which causes `bamfdaemon` (the program responsible for detecting running applications windows) to segfault. Perhaps try downgrading [`libwnck3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libwnck-3-0) to 40.1-1 if this happens